# Bash -- Double quotes within Backtick

Tags: bash, double, quotes

I'm using the following conditional in a bash script:

```
if `grep -q "${ACTION_LABEL} Action" "${OVERRIDE_ACTIONS}"`; then
  ....
fi
```

It basically works.  Except if any part of the path in ${OVERRIDE_ACTIONS} contains a space, then the grep fails.  How can I get this to work with paths containing spaces>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the backticks:

```
if grep -q "${ACTION_LABEL} Action" "${OVERRIDE_ACTIONS}"; then
    ...
fi
```

Why? `grep` will return a value of `0` if it succeeded in finding occurences for your pattern, or `1` if it failed. The body of the `if` statement will be executed, if the condition evaluates to `0`.